# Google Maps SDK for iOS: texts/labels (street names) in map refreshing when returning from another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, uiviewcontroller

I am working with Google Maps SDK for iOS using Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.4) and iOS simulator. The issue below also exists with my iPad running the same code with Xcode 7.1 and iOS 9.1.

I have created a mapView and a "Press" button in the default **ViewController**. After pressing the button, **ViewControllerB** is shown. If the "Back" button in **ViewControllerB** is pressed, the app goes back to the original **ViewController**.

**ViewController:**

[image: ViewController]

**ViewControllerB:**

[image: ViewControllerB]

I have found that texts (street names) in the mapView are refreshing when returning from ViewControllerB.

[Here is the video of this phenomenon.](https://youtu.be/k3ydsWBczOc)

My **ViewController**.swift:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate {

var mapView : GMSMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    println("viewDidLoad")

    mapView = GMSMapView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 100, view.bounds.width, view.bounds.height - 100))

    mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(25.047948, longitude: 121.517405, zoom: 15)

    mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeNormal
    mapView.delegate = self

    view.addSubview(mapView)

    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(50, 60, 200, 20))
    button.setTitle("Press", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "btnPressed:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(button)

}

func btnPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    let vcB = ViewControllerB()
    presentViewController(vcB, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

And **ViewControllerB**.swift:

```
class ViewControllerB: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let viewB = UIView(frame: view.frame)
    viewB.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    view.addSubview(viewB)

    let colorViewB = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, view.bounds.width, 60))
    colorViewB.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    view.addSubview(colorViewB)

    let labelB = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(100, 30 , 200, 25))
    labelB.text = "ViewControllerB"
    labelB.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    colorViewB.addSubview(labelB)

    let buttonBackB = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(20, 80, 100, 20))
    buttonBackB.setTitle("Back", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    buttonBackB.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    buttonBackB.addTarget(self, action: "btnBackB:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(buttonBackB)
}

func btnBackB(sender: UIButton) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
}
```

When returning to **ViewController**.swift, `viewDidLoad` and `mapView = GMSMapView()` are not called. So I don't know why the texts in the map are refreshing, but not the image part.

While testing with Apple's `MKMapView`, the street texts do not refresh after pressing "Back".

Is it possible to prevent the texts/labels in the map from refreshing?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of the labels being animated is private to `GMSVectorMapView`, a private class in the Google Maps SDK for iOS.

Here are some options for achieving the effect of not animating the labels:

1. Swizzle the private method that performs the update to override its behavior. I do not know what method that would be.
2. Make a snapshot of the view and show that first. After the appropriate delay, allowing the animation to update, show the map view while hiding the snapshot.
3. Make it so that you don’t trigger a view controller transition when navigating to and from the map. The labels do not animate if the view is hidden and unhidden.

You could also try making a request for this feature from the Google Maps SDK for iOS team.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have made a request for this feature.

Comment: That sounds like a good way to go. They have been responsive in fixing bugs in the past for me.